# Why does Emacs display with big fonts?

Tags: spacemacs, fonts

i just installed **Emacs 24.4** and i get this weird default theme with big fonts

[image: image one]
When I install spacemacs theme, I get this
[image]

Comment: Can you tell us more about the current operating system version? And what fonts are available in this os?

Comment: am using **ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

Answer (score 1):

it looks like it's the X server  which renders the fonts. After further digging,
the solution is right  [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1896584)
create a file 
 ~/.Xdefaults with the line

```
emacs*font: 7x14
```

and then running

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults
```